# Mail From header

Tags: php

Could some one point out why isnt the From: header working? Instead I am receiving something like myhost@conf....

```
<?php


$send=$_POST['send'];

if ($send){


$to="example@hotmail.com";
$subject=$_POST['subject'];

$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';

$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];

$body=$_POST['message'];

$mailers_name=ucwords($firstname);

if (!mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) 
    {
        header("LOCATION: http://www.mysite.co.uk/success.php?none=not");

}else {

    header("LOCATION: http://www.mysite.co.uk/success.php?none=yes");

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is your webhosting provider? are you using your own domain in the From address that your are specifying?

Comment: Yes I am using my own domain name

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `\r\n` in there at the end

`$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";`

OR

`$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\n";`

Comment: I believe that a trailing CRLF is not needed when setting additional headers in mail

Answer (score 1):

From the user notes at the PHP manual for [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), the following was posted by [me at arronwoods dot com](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#104594):

> I've had all sorts of problems with
>   scripts that don't set the "-f
>   user@example.org" parameter when using
>   mail() if postfix is the sendmail
>   agent.
>
> In postfix I had SMTP relay
>   authentication based on the sender
>   address, but it was always the PHP
>   user as the sender until I adapted the
>   code from:

```
<?php mail('test@example.org', 'Subject', 'Body', 'From: user@example.org'); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php mail('test@example.org', 'Subject', 'Body', 'From: user@example.org', '-f user@example.org'); ?>
```